# make not searching in include path

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm working through an OpenGL tutorial (OpenGL SuperBible 5) and I'm trying to get the supplied Makefile to work for my own program. I'm trying to get `make` to access a header file `GLTools.h` in my `/home/ben/lib/GLTools/include/` directory and I'm including it in my Makefile with `-I/home/ben/lib/GLTools/include/` (actually I'm using `-I$(SHAREDINCPATH)`) but `make` complains that there is no such file. Here is my `Makefile` (I've explicitly mentioned where I have edited the original `Makefile`):

```
MAIN = Triangle
SRCPATH = ./      # Edited: src is in CWD
SHAREDPATH = /home/ben/lib/GLTools/src/ # Edited to copied GLTools/src dir
SHAREDINCPATH = /home/ben/lib/GLTools/include/ # Edited to copied dir
LIBDIRS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib
INCDIRS = -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/GL -I$(SHAREDINCPATH)  -I$(SHAREDINCPATH)GL

CC = g++
CFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) -g $(INCDIRS)
LIBS = -lX11 -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm

prog : $(MAIN)

$(MAIN).o : $(SRCPATH)$(MAIN).cpp
glew.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)glew.c
GLTools.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)GLTools.cpp
GLBatch.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)GLBatch.cpp
GLTriangleBatch.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)GLTriangleBatch.cpp
GLShaderManager.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)GLShaderManager.cpp
math3d.o    : $(SHAREDPATH)math3d.cpp

$(MAIN) : $(MAIN).o glew.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(LIBDIRS) $(SRCPATH)$(MAIN).cpp $(SHAREDPATH)glew.c $(SHAREDPATH)GLTools.cpp $(SHAREDPATH)GLBatch.cpp $(SHAREDPATH)GLTriangleBatch.cpp $(SHAREDPATH)GLShaderManager.cpp $(SHAREDPATH)math3d.cpp $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

...and here is the `make` complaint:

```
ben@crunchbang:~/Code/C++/OpenGL/SuperBible5/SB5/Listings$ make
g++    -c -o Triangle.o Triangle.cpp
Triangle.cpp:4:50: fatal error: GLTools.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Triangle.o] Error 1
```

As a sanity check I'm printing out the location of `GLTools.h`:

```
ben@crunchbang:~/Code/C++/OpenGL/SuperBible5/SB5/Listings$ ls /home/ben/lib/GLTools/include/
GL             GLFrame.h              GLMatrixStack.h    GLTriangleBatch.h
GLBatchBase.h  GLFrustum.h            GLShaderManager.h  math3d.h
GLBatch.h      GLGeometryTransform.h  GLTools.h          StopWatch.h
```

Any idea why I cannot compile? I am pointing right at the `GLTools.h` with `INCDIRS`, right?

Also, I cannot find a declaration of `COMPILERFLAGS` anywhere in the makefile -- is this system-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for g++ you need to define in your makefile

```
CXXFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) -g $(INCDIRS)
```

And since you use both C files and C++ files then define both in your makefile:

```
CFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) -g $(INCDIRS)
CXXFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) -g $(INCDIRS)
```

CFLAGS is used by make when it compiles C files, CXXFLAGS is used when make compiles C++ files. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

```
CFLAGS

    Extra flags to give to the C compiler.
CXXFLAGS

    Extra flags to give to the C++ compiler.
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wonder why this worked for the original Makefile - I copied and pasted the source-code so everything should have been identical.